# android studio transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug after gradle 2.2

Tags: android, gradle-2

i have strange problem and i know it is was written before but all solutions not worked :(

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

it was debug before gradle 2.2

i have a week without any solution :(

----project lvl----
----build.gradle----

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


   }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
    }
  }
```

----app lvl----

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = 'com.czar.tunnel.cave'
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 12
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
        versionCode = 7
        versionName = '7.0'
    }
    ndk {
        platformVersion = 12
        moduleName = 'game'
        toolchain = 'clang'
        stl = 'gnustl_static' // recommending gnustl_static/gnustl_shared for android
        cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-Wall', // glm could not take -Wall -Werror
                         '-D GLM_FORCE_SIZE_T_LENGTH', '-D GLM_FORCE_RADIANS',
                         '-I' + file('src/main/jni'),
                         '-I' + file('src/main/jni/data')])
        ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'EGL', 'GLESv2', 'OpenSLES', 'log'])
    }


    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    project ':nativeactivity' linkage 'static'

                }
            }

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

android.lintOptions {
    abortOnError = false
}
}

 dependencies {
 compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
 compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

----module lvl----
----build.gradle----

----native activity gradle----

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
def ndkDir = System.getenv("ANDROID_NDK_HOME")
def propertiesFile = project.rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')

}

model {
    android {
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 12
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = '0.0.1'
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName = 'native-activity'
        ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'android'])
        ldFlags.add('-c')
    }
    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir "${ndkDir}/sources/android/native_app_glue"
                }
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "${ndkDir}/sources/android/native_app_glue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
 dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.4.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'  to 
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

it's work for me..

Comment: Thank you, brilliant solution